# how to cut substring from linux command "who"

Tags: linux, bash

command **who** returns list of users logged to server

```
[admin@DB01ATK ~]$ who
adm_drodmann pts/3        2015-07-01 08:57 (10.129.12.77)
adm_ssmith   pts/4        2015-07-01 02:11 (10.129.12.76)
adm_kholdman pts/2        2015-06-30 23:08 (10.129.12.45)
```

the point is to assign to variable, value of username($1) where terminal($2) is result from command

```
ps aux | grep screen
```

Comment: Use awk or similar, there are plently of questions on here explaining how to cut fields

Comment: well it is quite common I find myself an answer immediately after publishing a question.  My problem is almost solved. When I finish I publish full solution here.

Answer (score 0):

question asked question answered:

```
PTS=$(awk '{print $7}' <<< $(ps aux | grep screen) )
who | while  read CMD;
   do 
     res=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$CMD")
     if [ "$res" = "$PTS" ]
     then 
       echo "logged as $(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$CMD")"
     fi  
   done;
```

:-)

Comment: there is no need to do this, just say `while read res user _` and you will have the first value assigned to `$res` and the second one to `$user`. The rest will just fall into `$_`.

Comment: `awk` is overkill for just slicing a column. Use the right tool for the right job. In this case this would be `cut`.

Comment: @RamboRamon as I mention in my previous comment, not even `cut` is necessary. Also, there is not much difference in using cut or awk, both are external tools.

Comment: You are probably right. I thought he still need it for his `PTS` variable.

Comment: @RamboRamon in fact he does need it for the `$PTS` variable, you are right. I was thinking that the `ps` command can have more parameters to decide which columns to show, so that could also be a way.

Comment: To be honest, the whole construct `PTS=$(awk '{print $7}' <<< $(ps aux | grep screen) )` seems very doubtful to me. The inner command will usually return multiple lines, which is surely not desirable.

Comment: @RamboRamon yep, it will probably return the `grep` itself.

Comment: well, about ps aux | grep screen until now it always returned only one row.

Comment: fedorqui - your first hint is interesting. Would you explain "while read res user _"  how to implement it ? It is no clear for me ( but it seems it is shorter and better than my code)

Answer (score 0):

As per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155684/how-to-cut-substring-from-linux-command-who/31156251?noredirect=1#comment50331100_31156251) I expand my solution. You want to say:

```
ptw=$(ps aux | awk '/screen/ {print $7}')
while IFS=read -r user res _;
do 
    [ "$res" = "$PTS" ] && echo "logged as $user"
done < <(who)
```