# value of WHO comand returns in one line (instead of multilines)

Tags: linux, bash

This question is somehow connected to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155684/how-to-cut-substring-from-linux-command-who/31156251?noredirect=1#comment50324249_31156251) one

Command **who** typed from shell returns output like this

```
[admin@DB01ATK ~]$ who
adm_drodmann pts/3        2015-07-01 08:57 (10.129.12.77)
adm_ssmith   pts/4        2015-07-01 02:11 (10.129.12.76)
adm_kholdman pts/2        2015-06-30 23:08 (10.129.12.45)
```

the code below seems to be ( kind of) identical but output is in one line :

```
[admin@DB01ATK ~]$ who

adm_drodmann pts/3        2015-07-01 08:57 (10.129.12.77)
adm_ssmith   pts/4        2015-07-01 02:11 (10.129.12.76)
adm_kholdman pts/2        2015-06-30 23:08 (10.129.12.45)
[admin@DB01ATK ~]$  while  read CMD;
>      do
>        echo $(who)
>      done <<<$(who)
adm_drodmann pts/3 2015-07-01 08:57 (10.129.12.77) adm_ssmith   pts/4    2015-07-01 02:11 (10.129.12.76) adm_kholdman pts/2 2015-06-30 23:08 (10.129.12.45)
```

would you give me a hint how to split this looong string into lines

Comment: I believe what you want is `echo "$CMD"` instead of `echo $(who)`.

Comment: of course my mistake - **do echo $CMD done**

Comment: You also want `<<<"$(who)"` instead of `<<<$(who)`. Or, maybe better, `who | while read ...`.

Comment: ^^ "Or, maybe better" No, `<<<"$(who)" ` is generally preferred option. It modifies the variables in current shell.

Comment: well this is not so clear.   **<<<"$(who)"** return three lines - each line contains all values for who ( so it is kind of  database "cartesian")  I don't want to use **who | while read**  because in such a case variables inside do done are not visible outside loop.

Comment: @user3863616: you need to use both `echo "$CMD"` *and* `<<<"$(who)"`.

Comment: `while read l; do echo "$l"; done <<< "$(who)"`

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini - of course you are correct . Right now works as I expect.   Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you need to use both `echo "$CMD"` *and* `<<<"$(who)"`.

`while read l; do echo "$l"; done <<< "$(who)"`

– Andrea Corbellini